# What are good resources to do hands-on practice on network penetration testing?

Tags: penetration-test

Can anyone provide a good list of resources to learn network penetration testing? I am specifically looking for those having hands on exercises (kind of virtual labs/ISOs) which are free. I know web-apps like Mutillidae or even Google Gruyere are good resources for learning pentesting but these are good for web-app pen-testing. I am specifically searching for Network Pen-testing exercises. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Penetration Testing Practice Lab - Vulnerable Apps / Systems" http://www.amanhardikar.com/mindmaps/Practice.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the following:

- [Metasploitable](http://vulnhub.com/entry/metasploitable_1,28/) - The Metasploitable virtual machine is an intentionally vulnerable version of Ubuntu Linux designed for testing security tools and demonstrating common vulnerabilities.
- [Metasploitable 2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/metasploitable/files/Metasploitable2/) - The Metasploitable virtual machine version 2.
- [Damn Vulnerable Linux](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=dvl) - Damn Vulnerable Linux (DVL) is a Slackware and Slax-based live DVD. The distribution, purposefully stuffed with broken, ill-configured, outdated and exploitable software.

Edit: Fixed url to Metasploitable

Comment: Thnx for the distros! The metaspoitable link is actually contains URL for metasploitable 2. Do you have the URL for Metasploitable (1)

Comment: edited to fix the link, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://www.hacking-lab.com. They have a distro setup for the challenges they run

Good sources of info http://www.ethicalhacker.net and Security Tube

If you want resources to work on at home then download Kali Linux (install it, don't run it as a vm or cd/usb iso), Damn Vulnerable Linux, Damn Vulnerable Web App, VM-Ware/ Virtuabox and dig out a copy of XP.

As a minimum, you need to learn how to use NMap, Wireshark & Metasploit though you can cheat a little with Metasploit and use Armitage instead.

If I can find any further good links tonight, i'll post them.

Comment: Thanks for the first link! I was looking for a premade lab.

Answer (score 0):

The folks in offensive security are offering great course in infrastructure Pentesting check it out at: http://www.offensive-security.com/information-security-training/penetration-testing-with-kali-linux/

The course is comprehensive and will help you do real practice in their online labs, plus that its affordable.

I have some friends tried it and they are very happy with it.

Comment: It can be a tough course if you have no previous experience

Answer (score 0):

Hope these helps,

Books :

- Kali Linux Cookbook
- Metasploit Penetration Testing Cookbook
- Professional Penetration Testing, Second Edition: Creating and Learning in a Hacking Lab

Video :

- [Security Tube Metasploit](http://www.securitytube.net/groups?operation=view&groupId=10)  Free :D
- [Security Tube WLAN](http://www.securitytube.net/groups?operation=view&groupId=9)  Free :D

P.S. 
The more you explore the more your learn. If you have the desire you will find the luck.

Answer (score 0):

The best would of course be http://www.hackthissite.org/

It provides you with a lot of "missions".

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this and I would suggest a way to gain knowledge related to security, gain knowledge and skill up with tools and so on.

Go to the **[OWASP Testing Guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Testing_Guide_v4_Table_of_Contents)** it covered all the testing areas and vulnerabilities so start reading it and practice with the given tool for each testing.

For an example let's say **Testing for SQL Injection (OTG-INPVAL-005)** under **4.8 Input Validation Testing** so you can read about SQL Injection how it works and so on and then it shows **How to Test** also it provides **Tools** so use them for real world bug bounty programmes, ask questions online, take notes and in the end you **KNOW** and have **PRACTICED** something about SQL Injections go one by one in the end you will know the standard Pen-testing list.