# how to start penetration testing?

Tags: penetration-test, professional-education

I am currently working as security analyst on few applications and am willing to jump into penetration testing in future.To start with, what kind of skill set do i  need to develop like tools and concepts?
Please guide me with good learning web page links.

Comment: We can't really know the answer to that question because we don't know you or what kinds of penetration testing you want to do (network, application, web).

Comment: If you look on the side of this page at the "Related" list, do they help point you in the right direction? Like: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48139/what-are-good-resources-to-do-hands-on-practice-on-network-penetration-testing?rq=1

Comment: Sorry to mention which application needs to be undergone penetration testing.We have couple of web application for which penetration testing have to done.I would really appreciate any help on how to start penetration testing?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "web application testing". There are tons of resources to help you start, and the most obvious place is to know and understand the languages and technologies that those web applications have been built on.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean web-application penetration testing (you have not clarified), you can start by taking a look at OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project). They have many useful guidelines such as the [OWASP ASVS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Application_Security_Verification_Standard_Project) and [OWASP CVSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Threat_Risk_Modeling). These will guide you through basic testing methodologies and threat assessment techniques. From there, you can use this community to find answers to more specific questions.